# Do we really need the "fatal-error" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's currently 300+ questions tagged with [fatal-error](/questions/tagged/fatal-error) on Stack Overflow. Do we really need this tag? Is there any use for it outside of a meta tag?

Comment: Good catch. In my experience, it's a good indicator of a crappy question.

Comment: @Pekka Yeah, unless some practical use for it eludes me, I'm going to burninate it soon. There's several other in the meta 'error' family that may go with it, as the one thing they have in common is really smelly questions.

Comment: Yeah. My vote is for http://loyalkng.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/flamethrower.jpg

Comment: Oh my, 1,123 tagged [syntax-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax-error) Aaaaaaggggghhhhhh!

Comment: Can we synonymize it with `prognosis-negative` at least?

Comment: I am in fact an expert in language agnostic errors which terminate the program, but no other errors at all. Also sarcasm

Comment: No. Initiate destruction.

Answer (score 3):

It is used in completely different contexts to mean "I am getting a fatal error from this code," or "I need to handle a fatal error in my code."

Knowing that the question is being asked because a fatal error is not so important to require a tag; to me it is similar to [error](/questions/tagged/error).
I doubt there is somebody who is not going to answer a question just because it uses [fatal-error](/questions/tagged/fatal-error), or somebody who answer it because it has that tag.